# How do I bind a TreeView node to a specific view in an Explorer-like UI?

Tags: wpf, xml, mvvm, treeview, explorer

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this but I can't seem to find it. Most examples for binding TreeView nodes are about using a ListView to show the node's details. In the scenario I am working on I've got a TreeView data bound to an Xml document using a simple MVVM pattern. As each node is selected in the TreeView I want to show a different UserControl for the type of XmlNode being represented.

- What is the best control for hosting the different View's? (ViewBox, Panel?)
- What's the best way to bind the view to the Selection in the treeview?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an application I'm working on I have a similar scenario. You should use [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx) to host your views.

In the TreeView each item controls its own IsSelected state. Have you tried binding to the TreeView's [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditem.aspx) property? What I actually did was create an attached property for the mouse double click, and bound it to a [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx). I defined this binding in my [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx).

Comment: sounds about like what I am thinking. Just having trouble connecting the dots. (this is part of my learning wpf project). Any chance you could attach you datatemplates?